# eJabberd mysql_conn undef

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I just installed `eJabberd 2.1.13` manually with `--enable-odbc`

I am using an external auth, then I want the rosters to be on the MySQL database.

So I executed the `.sql` file included with `eJabberd` and included it on my existing database. I changed the `eJabberd` configuration to use `odbc_server mysql` with root mysql user. Tried running and saw an error about `undef, mysql_conn, start in function p1_fsm:terminate/7`

I have also changed the related mods to `*_odbc`.

Now `eJabberd` continues running where I can connect and stuff but I cant add friends.
What could be the reason why the mysql_conn is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

It probably can't connect to the db. Try verifying that mysql grants are properly set.
Also check that mysql is running (ps aux) and listening on the port ejabberd wants to connect to (probably 3306).
You may also try starting ejabberd in 'live' mode to get better hints.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the mysql source files first. I don't believe they ship with the regular ejabberd distribution. See: http://www.ejabberd.im/Using%20ejabberd%20with%20MySQL%20native%20driver, however the link to the source is broken. You can try this for the source code: https://github.com/dizzyd/erlang-mysql-driver. I think I used that repo awhile back. Process one also has a mysql driver repo: https://github.com/processone/mysql, but note the names are prepended with p1_.